# Nuxt generate publicPath wrongly appended to build path

Tags: path, nuxt.js

I'm importing a nuxt project in my framework.

It will be served at `/nuxtapp` and is available at `APP_ROOT/priv/static/nuxtapp` in my file structure.

I can't have assets loaded with the correct path. :(

Here's my config:

```
{
  build: {
    publicPath: '/nuxtapp/_nuxt/',
  },
  generate: {
    dir: '../priv/static/nuxtapp',
  }
}
```

The `publicPath` makes sure assets path in my HTML files is: `/nuxtapp/_nuxt/<hash>.js` which is what I'd expect.

The `generate` brings the code to `priv/static/nuxtapp` which is good too.

The only thing that doesn't work, is that the assets are placed in:

`APP_ROOT/priv/static/nuxtapp/nuxtapp/_nuxt/<hash>.js` while they should be at: `APP_ROOT/priv/static/nuxtapp/_nuxt/<hash>.js` so it feels exactly like file is moved at:

`${config.generate.dir}/${config.public_path}` while `publicPath` as its name suggests, should only be on the HTML side, as its name suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, I decided to move to `universal` [mode](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode/) which seems to be much more used hence have much less issues.

Not sure I would encourage Nuxt as a static site generator in `spa` mode, as document is still quite unclear and behaviors sometimes pretty mysterious.

But in `universal` mode, it is really great!